# Why do global variable get initialized by class in another source file?

Tags: c++, class, global-variables

For example, I have 2 sources with a class and a static function in each.
Both classes, functions and global variables has same names:
(I added functions only for comparision..)

```
//A.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

static bool FooFunc() { printf("Hello from function in A!\n"); return true; }

class FooClass
{
public:
    FooClass() { printf("Hello from class in A!\n\n"); }
};

static bool fooFunc = FooFunc();
static FooClass fooClass;
```

and

```
//B.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

static bool FooFunc() { printf("Hello from function in B!\n"); return true; }

class FooClass
{
public:
    FooClass() { printf("Hello from class in B!\n\n"); }
};

static bool fooFunc = FooFunc();
static FooClass fooClass;
```

Result:

```
Hello from function in A!
Hello from class in A!

Hello from function in B!
Hello from class in A!
```

Is class in 'B.cpp' gets ignored somehow?
If so, shouldn't compiler give me some error or warning?
I tried 'g++' and 'clang' compilers, same behavior.

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: Your program contains a violation of [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), and is therefore ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Comment: I'm using CodeLite IDE.

Comment: To clarify what Igor said: what you're doing is not allowed by the standard, but the standard says the compiler doesn't have to tell you.

Comment: To put it in yet another way - if you define `FooClass` in several translation units, **you** have to ensure that the classes are identical. And the compiler can assume that they are.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, thank you all for explanation!

Comment: To make them different classes, you can put them in different namespaces. Using anonymous namespaces would be ok.

Comment: Yes, anonymous namespaces fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++ a `source` file is called a translation unit(after the preprocessor). After the compilation of each unit the `object` files (.o) are then linked together by the linker. Now each class has a unique identifier when it's linked(so it can be put together with other translation units, to resolve variables etc). Your source files have the same class names yielding to a violation of the one definition rule. So, you have two choices. First is to rename one of the two classes and second to put them under a `namespace`. Hope I helped.